# Salesforce Validations - If Condition with And OR

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am trying to re-write a old validation and only have it flag on certain record types if the conditions are true.

I tried to Add an AND OR condition however it seems to be flagging all records

```
IF(
    ISBLANK(CreatedDate),
    AND(
        (Expiration_Date__c > (TODAY() +90)),
        (Expiration_Date__c < (TODAY() +180)), 
        ISBLANK(Expiration_Date_Explanation__c),
        AND(
            OR(
                $RecordType.Name = 'Sales',
                $RecordType.Name = 'Marketing'
            )
        )
    ),
    AND(
        (Quote_Expiration_Date__c > DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) +90),
        (Quote_Expiration_Date__c < DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) +180), 
        ISBLANK(Quote_Expiration_Date_Explanation__c),
        AND(
            OR(
                $RecordType.Name = 'Sales',
                $RecordType.Name = 'Marketing'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I wish Salesforce had Between but in either case my validation is firing on all records.

Comment: `IF(ISBLANK(CreatedDate),` is part of the only 1st query or both the queries?

Comment: That to me is where Salesforce is confusing... I believe that it says if Created Date is blank check the first query if not then do the second.

Comment: it is firing the first block or second block for all the records?

Comment: First block. So if i create a new record, on the validation object it flags regardless of the date

Comment: So whenever you are creating a new record, the `creation date` is blank, so it goes inside the first query. Did you tested it with any test record where All the condition inside the first block is false? for example, having expiration_data less than 90 days or greater than 180 days, not blank description, etc?

Comment: Yes as you were asking I tried it where created date is not blank... It appears not be firing at all.

Comment: AND 
( 
OR 
( 
$RecordType.Name = "Sales", 
$RecordType.Name = "Marketing" 
), 
(Expiration_Date__c > DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) +90), 
(Expiration_Date__c < DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) +180), 
ISBLANK(Expiration_Date_Explanation__c) 

)

Comment: If I take out the IF condition and just did it for records to be edited, I believe the above should work but no validation on todays date or a date i want such as Sept 12th

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194181/discussion-between-vishal-and-codemonger).

Comment: Thanks I just figured it out.......... Thanks for the chatting, I used the Record Type Name where apparently I needed to use the Label!!!!!!!! UGH..